# Tags that could also be topics

Tags: support, documentation

I was just looking over the Python docs and decided to have a look at the SQLAlchemy info. Firstly, I tried searching by name for it under the python tag and didn't find it even though there are a few modules as topics, and a few sql modules in particular. As the sqlalchemy docs seem to be a bit larger though they have been put under their own tag, so don't show up for a search actually in python, for sql.

with some link as asked. for [python documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/topics), under the tag, [an sql search](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/search?tag=python&query=sql) doesn't show details for [sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sqlalchemy/topics), as its got enough topics to warrant its own tag, even though it is specifically about a python module.

So is it possible to associate one tag as connected with another, for searching like this, and what would be the way to do it if so?

In particular, if I didn't know it's name and association with Python, I wouldn't be likely to find it searching for sql in general

Comment: @Frank - links added.

Comment: Ok, I'd just make a simple topic about it under python Docs and put a link to the sqlalchemy Docs there. Similarly, the "intro to sqlalchemy" Doc should/could have a link back to the python Docs. That's more or less the plan for R libraries (though, for now, I'm not adding links since I don't want the library's Docs inundated with bad edits).

Comment: Ah, cool. Will check that out when I'm on a proper computer! Cheers.

Comment: @Guy FYI The current recommendation is to only have native language features covered in the language tag, and cover libraries in their own tags.